# Win Form Charting

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I may be asking the wrong question, but what I need is to add a "Guide Line" to my windows form chart. In other words I have a chart with a simple data series and I need to draw a line on the y axis at the passing score, or 80%. I don't want to add a second series as the first series has an undetermined number of data points. Is there a simple way to simply draw one line on the y axis?
The dashed line below is what I am shooting for(it does not need the arrows).

```
100|
   |
 90|
   |                     o
 80|<----------------------->
   |
 70|      o                  o
   |
 60|         o
   |   o        o
 50|o              o
   |_________________________
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Comment: +1 for the awesome diagram ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add  a [StripLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.stripline.aspx).

Use [`StripWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.stripline.stripwidth.aspx) property to set line position:

```
var series = chart1.Series[0]; //series object
var chartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea];
chartArea.AxisY.StripLines.Add(new StripLine
                                           {
                                               BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash,
                                               BorderColor = Color.DarkBlue,
                                               StripWidth = 80//Here is your y value
                                           });
```

**UPDATE:** Previous version of this answer used [`Interval`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.stripline.interval.aspx) instead of `StripWidth`. As @dthor [correctly pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503043/win-form-charting/7503876?noredirect=1#comment71992882_7503876) setting the `Interval` will draw a repeated strip line. In the example above, `Interval` is set to 0 by default.

Comment: All in all this was the easiest solution, it took me a few to figure out the Interval piece, but since my chart goes from 0 to 100, I made the interval 85, and whala effect created. Thank you Makkam.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the lines will end up repeating if you go above the interval. For example, a plot that's *typically* from 0-100 with a stripline interval of 80. If the plot value gets to 160, another stripline will be shown at 160.

Comment: @dthor Fixed that. Better late than never :) Thank you very much for pointing out this bug.

Answer (score 8):

Apologies for repeating Don Kirkby's answer, but I don't have the rep to add a comment yet.

Using [HorizontalLineAnnotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.horizontallineannotation.aspx) you can set the [ClipToChartArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.annotation.cliptochartarea.aspx) which will limit the extent of the line to within the chart, to solve the problem you mentioned.

```
ChartArea area = ...;

var line = new HorizontalLineAnnotation();
line.IsInfinitive = true; // make the line infinite
line.ClipToChartArea = area.Name;
line.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
```

Assuming your y-axis holds values on a scale of 0..1 then you can attach the line to the Y-Axis using `line.AxisY = area.AxisY`, which results in its position being interpreted as an axis value, then set `line.Y = 0.8;` to attach at the 80% position.

Comment: Ahh so that is how you use that annotation. Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't worry about repeating my answer, you added a bunch of helpful info. I was surprised that the MSDN docs didn't contain examples for any of the annotations I looked at.

Comment: It looks like you also need this at the end: chart1.Annotations.Add(line);

Answer (score 2):

I've never used charts, but [HorizontalLineAnnotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.horizontallineannotation.aspx) sounds promising.

Comment: HorizontalLineAnnotation is nice, but it exceeds the bounds of the inner chart area.

Answer (score 0):

You can add dots to the frame with a loop that has for example 900 loop for 1 to 9 values. For each loop the compiler will calculate the value and left a dot for that perimeter and another for the next one so it will looks like a line of a equation :)

Comment: This dirty option works as well, but its not quite right for what I am trying to achieve.