# Windows Forms Chart - Add A Value Marker

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I've created a chart in windows forms where the X axis has DateTime values (hh:mm:ss). I'd like to add a fixed line to the chart on a certain value - for example, have a line on the grid for X = 07:00:00. Is this possible? Can I put in multiple such lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Dominique, I poked around for some StripLine examples and eventually this is the code I used:

```
StripLine stripLine = new StripLine();
// highlight a strip of 8 hours in the X axis
stripLine.StripWidth = 8;
stripLine.StripWidthType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
stripLine.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.PapayaWhip;
stripLine.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSeaGreen;
stripLine.BorderWidth = 2;
// start the highlighting 7 hours in (from 07:00 to 15:00)
stripLine.IntervalOffset = 7;
stripLine.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
// repeat this strip every 1 day
stripLine.Interval = 1;
stripLine.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
this.TopOfBookChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Add(stripLine);
```

With it I produced [the following graph](http://s7.postimage.org/etnha69bt/Time_Highlight.jpg).

You can find another (simpler) example here: [Win Form Charting Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503043/win-form-charting)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve your goal using by adding properly configured `StripLine` objects to the right axis. See the [MS Chart Winsamples](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) for details on how to use all the features of the charting controls.