# HorizontalLineAnnotation resizing

Tags: c#, winforms

Following response from question [Win Form Charting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503043/win-form-charting?lq=1) I'm trying to use HorizontalLineAnnotation on Windows Forms Chart. Using code:

```
 private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Series series = SampleChart.Series.First();
    ChartArea area = SampleChart.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea];
    HorizontalLineAnnotation line = new HorizontalLineAnnotation()
    {
        AxisX = area.AxisX,
        AxisY = area.AxisY,
        ClipToChartArea = area.Name,
        X = 50,
        Width = 15,
        Y = 120,
        Height = 40,
        LineWidth = 1,
        LineColor = Color.Red,
        LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dot,
        AllowMoving = true,
        AllowResizing = true
    };
    SampleChart.Annotations.Add(line);
}
```

According to MSDN protperties AllowMoving and AllowResizing should let me move and resize the annotation using the mouse. Unfortunately while AllowMoving works like charm, AllowResizing seems to be ignored. Or, maybe it's not working how I think it's working. Anyone has any experience with this control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `AllowSelecting = true` on the `HorizontalLineAnnotation`. This allows the user to select the line and gives grab handles (small squares) at each end when the line is selected to allow resizing as per the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Just when I lost all hope. :) It works, thank you. I wish such information was in msdn. :)